# Gulp build command gives me this error message

Tags: gulp

```
$ gulp build
[02:36:37] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\gulpfile.js
[02:36:37] Starting 'build'...
[02:36:37] Starting 'clean:dist'...
[02:36:37] Finished 'clean:dist' after 4.63 ms
[02:36:37] Starting 'sass'...
[02:36:37] Starting 'useref'...
[02:36:37] Starting 'img'...
[02:36:37] Starting 'cleancss'...
[02:36:37] Finished 'cleancss' after 37 ms
C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\gulp-useref\node_modules\vinyl- 
fs\lib\src\index.js:20
throw new Error('Invalid glob argument: ' + glob);
^

Error: Invalid glob argument:
at Object.src (C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\gulp- 
useref\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:20:11)
at DestroyableTransform.addAssetsToStream 
(C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:62:15)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:124:31
at Array.forEach (native)
at DestroyableTransform.processAssets 
(C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:115:11)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:178:31
at Stream.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\gulp- 
useref\node_modules\event-stream\index.js:318:20)
at _end (C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\through\index.js:65:9)
at Stream.stream.end 
(C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\through\index.js:74:5)
at DestroyableTransform.onend 
(C:\xampp\htdocs\melodic\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable- 
stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:577:10)
```

I have tried to remove the running tasks one by one but to no avail. What throws me off also is the fact that it seems to run through all the tasks and even finishing them and then crashing as the last task is finished. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is my gulpfile as I forgot to include it.

```
     var gulp = require('gulp');
     // Requires the gulp-sass plugin
     var sass = require('gulp-sass');
     //Requires browser synch
     var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
     //Requires userref
     var useref = require('gulp-useref');
     //Requires uglify
     var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
     var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');
    //Requires cssnano
    var cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
    //Requires imagemin
    var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
    //Requires cache
    var cache = require('gulp-cache');
    //Requires del
    var del = require('del');
    //Requires run-sequence
    var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
    //requires postcss
    var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

    //ACTIVE COMMANDS

    /*Run 'gulp browserSync' in commandline.
    This task automatically reloads the broswer upon each save of document*/
    gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
    injectChanges: true,
    server: {
      baseDir: "./app"
    },
  })
});



/*Run 'gulp sass' in command line.
THIS TASK GETS ALL SCSS IMPORTED INTO THE app.scss FILE AND CONVERTS IT INTO app.css.
THIS TASK IS A ONE TIME CONVERSTION*/
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}));
});



/*Run 'gulp watch' in command line.
THIS TASK GETS ALL SCSS AND OTHER FILE TYPES AND CONVERTS THEM ACITVELY.
THIS TASK IS ONGOING*/
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function (){
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});



//PRODUCTION/FINAL COMMANDS


/*Run 'gulp useref' in command line.
THIS TASK GETS ALL CSS AND OTHER FILE TYPES AND JOINS DIFFERENT FILES AND MINIMIZES THEM IN THE DIST FOLDER.
*/
gulp.task('useref', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    // Minifies only if it's a JavaScript file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

gulp.task('cleancss', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});

/*Run 'gulp img' in command line.
MINIMIZSES PHOTOS TO THE DIST FOLDER*/
gulp.task('img', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
  .pipe(imagemin({
    // Setting interlaced to true
    interlaced: true
  }))
    // Caching images that ran through imagemin
  .pipe(cache(imagemin({
      interlaced: true
    })))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
});

/*Run 'gulp fonts' in command line.
CLEANS THE DIST DIRECTORY FOR UNUSED FILES*/
gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
  return del.sync('dist');
});


/*Run 'gulp fonts' in command line.
CLEANS THE IMAGE CACHE CREATED EARLIER*/
gulp.task('cache:clear', function (callback) {
return cache.clearAll(callback)
});


gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
  runSequence('clean:dist',
    ['sass', 'useref', 'img', 'cleancss'],
    callback
  )
});

gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
  runSequence(['sass','browserSync', 'watch'],
    callback
  )
  });
```

EDIT: Included my gulpfile for further details.

Comment: Please post the gulpfile you use

Comment: @Vasan I included the gulpfile now :)

Comment: Your .html is located in app/*.html?

Comment: @Mark Yes my index.html file is in my app directory.

Comment: @Zcylon Did you find a solution?